# Get current character index in Word Add-in

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I am using this control here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11819/Integrating-Microsoft-Word-in-your-NET-application

and the good thing about this control is, it is using Word Interop so I can manipulate word documents using  [Word Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx) with Application, Document, Selection, Range, and Bookmark objects.

I am trying to search for a words in a document; all words enclosed with double quotes. I am using RegEx for this just by taking the text out in **Document.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Text** and by using these taken words, my application will look for word matches in the current document that are not in the same character case like for example in my collection I have "Business Name", and the application will look in the document for possible matches like: business name, Business name, business Name using RegEx. I needed the RegEx because I need to get the index of the word so when a user clicked on the lists where it shows the possible matches, it will automatically highlight in the document using

```
document.Application.Selection.SetRange(index, index);
document.Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
document.Application.Selection.Find.Execute(s_word, MatchCase: true);
```

the issue here is, sometimes the word does not get highlighted because the SetRange is at the wrong index position because I used RegEx to get the [Match.Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index(v=vs.110).aspx)

My question is, is there any alternative way of looking for possible matches that I can also have the index so when the user clicked this word in the lists, it will highlight the word without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not as far as I know.

The character index in Word will get off when having tables, images, and some other special objects. For [one of our projects](http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-composition-for-word), we had the same issue. We found no reliable way to match the character position in plain text, to an index in Word.

That's the reason we reverted to the OpenXML format to get the text out in a reliable way, but that needs a lot of extra work to get that going.

You could try to use `Find`, when you have an approximate location. Just search starting from `calculated position - 10` to find the text, *most likely* you will find the exact position then, which you can use to highlight.

Comment: @Jayson: need more help?